# iChat Screen Sharing - Keyboard shortcut to switch back to my computer without messing with the mouse that is being used by the other user?

Tags: display, ichat

When you are watching a screen sharing session commanded by the other user, in other words, you are watching the other user doing stuff in his computer, how do I switch back to my computer without disrupting the other user by stealing the mouse to click on the "My Computer" window?

Put simply: To go back to my computer I have to click in the "My computer" little window at the bottom, but that requires me to use the mouse which is being used by the other user. There must be a way to use a keyboard shortcut to perform that action without bothering the other user who is using the mouse to do something important.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You could press the Power-button on your Mac and use Cmd-Tab to switch to another app.

Kind of ugly, but at least the user won't lose control of the mouse.

Credits to Justintosh @ http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=11607637